# RadioButtons save last checked instead of desired one when form displayed again

Tags: delphi, radio-button

I have some `TRadioButton`s on `Form2` and call `Form2` from `Form1` with this code:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnCallForm2Click(Sender:TObject);
begin
  Form2.RadioButton2.Checked:= true;
  Form2.ShowModal;
end;
```

If user clicked `btnCallForm2`, `Form2` will be displayed, then user clicks `RadioButton3` and closes the form, and then reopen it by clicking `btnCallForm2` again.

Now `Form2` displayed again but `RadioButton3` is checked instead of `RadioButton2`.

**Q:** What is this behavior, is it a bug? How to set checked my desired `RadioButton` instead of what is selected by the user in previous turn?

Comment: It's not a bug. You are just concatenating `Caption` with the current `Caption` and control name. Write just `Caption := (Sender as TComponent).Name;`

Comment: `Caption` is refer to the form caption it's the same as `Form1.Caption` or `Self.Caption`. When you write `Caption:= Caption` this mean the prev `Form.Caption` + `(Sender as TComponent).Name`. So as @TLama already said use `Caption := (Sender as TComponent).Name;` instead of `Caption:= Caption + (Sender as TComponent).Name;`

Comment: @TLama, problem is not the caption (despite the fact that it's cleared before ShowModal in the btnCallForm2Click) . It's RadioButton that is not what I want to be selected.

Comment: @Sami, with Caption I just want to show you that RadioButton is checked twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug. The reason that you have this "strange" behavior is that if the Form2 is not destroyed, then next time it becomes visible (e.g. `ShowModal`) it remembers which control had the focus.

In your case the last control in focus is the RadioButton3 (because you clicked on it to change the "checked" state). So even if you are changing the "checked" state back to RadioButton2, the focus will be restored to RadioButton3 when the form is next activated. To restore the focus, the control is sent a `WM_SETFOCUS`. Read the rest from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-messages#button-default-message-processing) for default message processing for button controls:

> [**WM_SETFOCUS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-setfocus)   Draws a focus rectangle on the button getting the focus.
>   For radio buttons and automatic radio buttons, the parent window is
>   sent a [BN_CLICKED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) notification code.

This `BN_CLICK` notification (`WM_COMMAND` message) sets the state of the radio button to checked.

The rationale behind this behavior can be found while navigating the radio buttons with the keyboard. When you press up/down arrow while on one of the radio buttons, the next radio button that receives the focus becomes checked.

This behavior only applies to radio buttons, e.g., try the same with another control (e.g. check box), that its state is not altered when it has focus. You will see that everything is working as expected

As kobik was suggesting, a fast and easy solution would be to set the ActiveControl to nil before showing the Form2

```
Form2.ActiveControl := nil;
```

or in the light of the documentation:

```
Form2.ActiveControl := Form2.RadioButton2;
```

or you could destoy and recreate the form as following:

Remove the Form2 from the AutoCreated Forms in Project->Options->Forms and create it manually in the ButtonClick event

```
procedure TForm1.btnCallForm2Click(Sender:TObject)
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    Form2.RadioButton2.Checked:= true;
    Form2.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Form2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Personally I would go for the same approach. But why is that *needed*? Why the behavior OP described? that is IMO the real question.

Comment: @kobik, answered updated to cover the explanation for the described behavior.

Comment: Ok, you convinced me that the focused control plays part here. I still think its a bad design and the behavior was unexpected, at-least to me. In  any case another solution would be to set `Form2.ActiveControl := nil` before showing it.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I consider auto generated forms a bad choice. IMO only the Main form should be auto generated, and all other forms should be created dynamically on demand. so `"Freeing and recreating the whole form seems like a rather dramatic solution"` - is actually a good advice. what i suggested is an ugly workaround, and even after going over the VCL code I can't pin point exactly **where** the "focus" thing takes place.

Comment: @kobik - I slightly modified the answer to explain the behavior. @ Magic - I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Sertac, Thank you for shading some light on this.

Comment: @Sertac of course I don't mind, thank you for the detailed explanation.